# How to share a specific variable between different react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 sibling components **home** and **history** where home has the following function

```
//home
function handledata() {
    const key = uuidv4();
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(formdata));
  }
```

I need to access local storage in the sibling **history** component so how do i access this key variable there

```
//history
const [items, setItems] = React.useState([]);
  const handledata = () => {
    localStorage.getItem(key);
  };
```

Complete code of both files https://github.com/Megahedron69/testrep

Answer (score 2):

You're best option is to `decouple` localstorage from both the components & make a it a separate module or a class. Then you can access it in both the files.

*Pseudocode*

```
class LocalStorage {

  setItem(key, item) { ... }
  getItem(key) { ... }

}
```

If you don't want to do that - [Lifting the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) up is the best possible solution when want to share data between sibling components.

Make a `parent` component of `home` & `history` & use `localstorage` there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `handledata` function in that case.
You can just access localStorage without it:

```
 const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
 // use this data any way you want in the component
```

Answer (score 0):

Ways to share data between states:

1. The parent component.
2. Localstorage
3. Global State management

Local storage is not recommended for this stuff and in your case global state doesn't make sense. Parent state is better in your case.

There are multiple things you can do:

1. Generate key in parent and share it in both components
2. Create a state in parent component in parent and then set that state in **history**